The exit code -1073741819 in clion in C language
I've been trying to build the practice code, but after the step(to get the cordinate through scanf function)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#define pi 3.1415926535

struct point {
    int x;
    int y;
};

struct circle {
    struct point center;
    double radius;
};

double Area(struct circle circle) { //s = ㅠr^2
    double area = 0;
    return area = circle.radius * circle.radius * (pi);
}

double Round(struct circle circle) {
    double Round = 0;
    return Round = 2 * pi * circle.radius;
}

int main(void) {
    struct circle circle = {0, 0, 0};

    printf("The center of the circle (fomat : (x, y)) : ");
        scanf("%d %d", circle.center.x, circle.center.y);
    printf("The radius of the circle : ");
        scanf("%d", circle.radius);

    printf("The arae of the circle : %f ", Area(circle));

    printf("The round of the circle : %f", Round(circle));

    return 0;
}

the program shut down with the exit code -1073741819. I can't understand what is the matter of the code:

ps.I just changed my "%d" to unify the type of the data as the float. It's still not working.

Now, I just fixed the mistake to add the "&" in froint of the variable. It may sounds rude although, I wish anyone let me know the reason of  printing the -1073741819 in the teriminal if the "&" is missed in "scanf" function.

Hint: when scanf gets the pointer, it writes to the memory at the pointed-to address. What happens if instead of the pointer it gets some unrelated integer?

Always enable warnings and read them. The compilers will show you the issue immediately

Please don't post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.

In scanf("%d", arg), arg is supposed to be an int*. When extracting an int from stdin, scanf will then write that int to *arg. Since you provide the values held by your circle members instead of pointers to those members, those values may be interpreted as int* - and the value you provide is 0 so you are effectively telling scanf to write the result to address 0 which is very unlikely an address you are allowed to write to.
If sizeof(int) is less than sizeof(int*), say they are 4 and 8, scanf will also try to extract 8 bytes where you've supplied 4 (your int).
In scanf("%d", circle.radius); you also use %d but circle.radius is a double so %lf should be used.
Supplying the wrong argument for the conversion specifier has undefined behavior and the program could crash - or worse. The exit code -1073741819 in Windows means "Access Violation" and most probably comes from scanf trying to write to address 0.
You need to change these:
scanf("%d %d", circle.center.x, circle.center.y);
scanf("%d", circle.radius);

into these:
if (scanf("%d %d", &circle.center.x, &circle.center.y) != 2) { /* error */ }
if (scanf("%lf", &circle.radius) != 1) { /* error */ }


The precise meaning of exit codes (other than 0 == OK) generally depends on the operating system.  The code -1073741819 corresponds to the 32-bit hex code C0000005, which leads one to suspect you are running on Windows, where a C0000005 exit code means "Access Violation".  This generally means the program crashed due to a buffer overrun or invalid pointer.
This is roughly equivalent to a SIGSEGV on Linux, which often shows up as an exit code of 139.
